# Convert base64URLEncode (in javascript) to php

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode, cryptojs, base64url

I have a code in javascript. I want to convert it in php.
I don't know how to convert this: str.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)

```
function base64URLEncode(str) {
  return  str.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64).replace(/=/g, '').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to decode base64 in PHP?

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.base64-decode.php

And encoding of course:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php